# Tomcat 6 browser from some proxies are unable to resolve url

Tags: url, tomcat6

I have configured my server.xml with host name=myweb and hosted it on a server but I am having problems as few of my friends are able to access the site using myweb:8081/App/welcome.jsp
but some are unable to do it but I found out that those people are who were unable to do so using the above url are able to access the site using the complete server url such as gvad.sc.pe:8081/App/welcome.jsp

Any Ideas that I can solve it?

Comment: without your complete server.xml, it will be difficult to answer you... Wich version of Tomcat do you use ?

Comment: Tomcat 6 ..is there a way to reconfigure the dns tree??... If some of us are using different proxy ?

Comment: Do you have a firewall on your machine ?
There's nothing in tomcat conf that can handle your DNSs

Comment: Yes that seems the case with me.. Thanks Grooveek...